# returning a std::string with an vector

Tags: c++, iteration, stdstring, stdvector

I'm trying to get "CMtoaPlugin::listArnoldNodes()" to return an "array" of strings

```
   std::vector<std::string> ArnoldNodes = CMtoaPlugin::listArnoldNodes();
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;

   for ( it=ArnoldNodes.begin() ; it < ArnoldNodes.end(); it++ )
   {
      printf("initialize shader %s\n", *it);
   }
```

but this is what i get, 2 entries, that's correct but the content of the entry is not

initialize Arnold shader †¡/

initialize Arnold shader.

what am i doing wrong

Comment: You'll have to show us the code in listArnoldNodes().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
for (it = ArnoldNodes.begin() ; it != ArnoldNodes.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << "initialize shader " << *it << std::endl;
}
```

- `printf` doesn't work with `std::string`, you need to use `cout` (or pass it `it->c_str()`)
- In an iterator for-loop, it's preferable to use `it != vec.end()` (since you only need to check for equality, not compare), and `++it` to increment (post-increment can be less efficient for some iterators).

Answer (score 7):

You can not print a std::string with printf (or any varargs method).  g++ gives a warning here:

```
warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type ‘struct std::string’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
```

Just use cout:

```
std::cout << "initialize shader " << *it << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to print the C-string corresponding to `std::string` with `printf`, like this:

```
 printf("initialize shader %s\n", it->c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you for-loop across your iterator range, you should be performing it using :

```
for ( it = ArnoldNodes.begin() ; it != ArnoldNodes.end(); it++ )
{ /*...*/ }
```

the difference is that the comparison is `!=` instead of `<`, because `container.end()` iterators return one-past-the-end of the container. It's not necessarily more "correct", but it is more idiomatic.

Comment: True; the reason, however, is not that `container.end()` is past-the-end, but because loops written with `<` only work for RandomAccessIterators, whereas `!=` works for all of them.